# Why add empty curly braces in createContext() to help handle API data

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Say I have the following in my Context component:

```
export const AppContext = createContext({});

export const Provider = ({children}) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.get(<apiUrl>)
                       .then(data => setData(data.data));      
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

// etc. code below
```

I then call `useContext(appContext)` in another component to retrieve the prop carrying the data from this provider.

This prop holds API data which is an array of objects. In a certain circumstance, I would want to grab only the data from the first object of this array by writing `prop[0]`. Now maybe I want to grab the value from a certain property of this object by then writing `prop[0].objProp`

My question: Why does this only work when there are empty curly braces inside the `createContext()` call at the beginning of the example? Because without that, I would receive the error "Property 'objProp' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

You are not showing all relevant code to determine what exactly is going wrong, but my guess is that you have not provided a value for the `value` prop when rendering `AppContext.Provider`.

According to the documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext):

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree.

So if a matching provider is not found the default value of of `createContext` is used. If you don't pass anything this will be `undefined`, if you pass `{}` it will be an object.

Let's say you have the following code:

```
const c = React.useContext(AppContext)
console.log(c.value)
```

When `createContext` is not passed a default argument the previous code will error, because you try to access a property on `undefined`. If the default value was set, the value of `c.value` will just be `undefined`, because there is no property named `something` on an empty object.

---

#### Working Example

Now what I actually think you should do is to provide the `value` prop on `AppContext.Provider` and do something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([{title: ''}]); // Need default value with all fields in the object you plan on receiving

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      await axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data.data);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{data: data}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const TestComponent = () => {
  const c = React.useContext(AppContext) 
  return c.data[0].title // Do something with the data...
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Provider>
        <TestComponent />
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I appreciate your wording of this explanation and the provided suggestions. Thank you @BasvanderLinden! I do have a git repo for you to view with changes I made from your suggestion, if you are able to verify. It's a weather app project I am still working on in its initial stages. https://github.com/TylerAPfledderer/weather-app-react.git